# Why increase a value in this way in python?

Tags: python

I've found an example of a code in python, and I understand the code but there is one line that I don't know why is wrote that way:

```
c = 1    
c = (c + 1) & 255
```

I know it increments the value of the variable C in one, but I don't understand the `& 255`

can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What this code does is reset `c` to zero when it reaches 256, so the sequence goes:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ... -> 254 -> 255 -> 0 -> 1 -> ...
```

It is another way to write:

```
c = (c + 1) % 256
```

One way to think about this is that the `% 256` restricts the range of the result to `0`..`255`.

Note that the `& 255` only works because `256` is a power of two, whereas the formulation using the modulus operator works for any number.

Comment: The other reason for using `& 255` is that it makes explicit that you're mimicing an 8-bit integer, not performing a mathematical operation.  (`& 0xFF` would be even clearer for this reason.)

Comment: thanks! I think this is the best explanation for the code I'm using. It makes totally sense to me now.

Answer (score 5):

The `&` operator is a bitwise and. Each bit in the result is `1` if and only if the corresponding bits in both arguments are `1`. Let's look at some examples:

```
>>> a = 10 # 0b1010
>>> b = 12 # 0b1100
>>> bin(a & b)
0b1000
>>> a = 300 # 0b100101100
>>> b = 255 # 0b011111111
>>> bin(a & b)
'0b101100'
```

You may have noticed that 255 is `0b011111111`, and the way `&` works, this means that the result will have the same last 8 bits as the other argument, and no other bits.

This is a good way to mask a value to fit into a byte (an 8-bit unsigned integer) by "rolling over" and ignoring any overflow. You can similarly use 31 or 65535 to mask a value into a nybble or a word.

So, this code:

```
c = (c + 1) & 255
```

… means that we're treating `c` as a byte, incrementing it, and rolling over and ignoring any overflow.<sup>*</sup>

This can be a useful thing to do if `c` really does represent some low-level byte-oriented value that acts this way, like an LED counter that cycles through 256 positions and starts back at the beginning on a RPi board.

---

In C, some people use it as a shortcut for `% 256` even when the value really isn't meant to represent a byte, just because it gives the same result and, at least in C on 1970s hardware, it's a lot faster. But in C on 2015 hardware, it may not actually be faster. And in Python, it almost certainly isn't. (In fact, from a quick test, it's slightly *slower*… but it's also so close that, even if that isn't a measurement error, you're never going to care.)

So, if you see anyone writing this as an "optimization" in Python, you should take their interpreter away and make them work in assembly language for a week until they get over it.

---

<sub>* As sapi points out in a comment on [NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30420641/908494), it would probably be clearer to write this as `& 0xFF`, or maybe `& 0b11111111`, because either of those is more obviously the highest byte value than `255` is.</sub>

Comment: @Kasra: Thanks for the edit. That trivial mistake made the rest of my answer make no sense…

Comment: @Kasra: Are you quoting Tron: Uprising?

Comment: Its : *a bit can change the world ;)* but i don't remember when i have encounter with this quote, i think it was in a book about linux.

Comment: Is such dialog in Tron: Uprising?

Comment: @Kasra: I think Mara said it in one of the later episodes, the one where she got drugged into admiring Clu and hating Tron. But the show could easily have been referencing a more famous quote that I didn't get…

Comment: Aha, it must be interesting!! :)

Comment: thanks for this explanation, it was very informative.

Answer (score 3):

`x % (2 ^ N)` is equal to `x & ((2 ^ N) -1)`. The `&` is bit operator. This is for optimization since modulo is slow, but bit operation is fast.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Comment: Or this is for pessimization. From a quick test in CPython 3.5a4 on a Mac,  the modulo version takes 21.2ns, and the and version takes 21.8ns. In Python (at least CPython) the costs of interpreting the bytecodes and boxing and unboxing the values will swamp the cost of the actual modulo or bit operation, and even in C on a modern system there's a good chance that if the compiler doesn't optimize your code the CPU will… So no one should write this code in Python for performance. Of course if you're writing it to explicitly signal "this is 8-bit unsigned int arithmetic", that's good.

Comment: Interesting, I just checked on 2.7 default python interpreter, the and version is (still) slightly faster, but only a friction

In [57]: timeit.timeit(stmt='c = (c + 1) & 255', setup='c=0', number=1000000)
Out[57]: 0.10145187377929688

In [58]: timeit.timeit(stmt='c = (c + 1) % 256', setup='c=0', number=1000000)
Out[58]: 0.12007594108581543

In [59]: timeit.timeit(stmt='c = (c + 1) & 255', setup='c=0', number=10000000)
Out[59]: 0.9757719039916992

In [60]: timeit.timeit(stmt='c = (c + 1) % 256', setup='c=0', number=10000000)
Out[60]: 1.1269760131835938

Comment: It probably depends on your machine, and also what value you use. For me, with the number `0` or `2`, the `&` is definitely a bit faster; with the number `20000`, the `%` is faster (but so close that I wouldn't trust it to be meaningful). At any rate, if this ever is actually the bottleneck in your code, you'd want to test it, not guess based on what was faster in C on a PDP-11. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is only slightly faster.

Modulo:

```
%timeit 2 % 255
10000000 loops, best of 3: 37.7 ns per loop
```

Bitwise:

```
%timeit 2 & 255
10000000 loops, best of 3: 33.3 ns per loop
```

I think using modulo is more pythonic.

More timings suggest that both ways take the same amount of time:

```
%timeit 100 % 256
10000000 loops, best of 3: 34 ns per loop

%timeit 100 & 256
10000000 loops, best of 3: 33 ns per loop
```

Doing it often enough you will find a reverse relation:

```
%timeit 256 % 256
10000000 loops, best of 3: 33.7 ns per loop

%timeit 256 & 256
10000000 loops, best of 3: 34.5 ns per loop
```

Re-running the test will yield slightly different numbers. So sometimes
one is faster than the other and vice versa.

Comment: You want to test `% 256`, not `% 255`. And on my system, I get 20.9ns vs. 21.0ns for 2, and 21.2ns vs. 21.9ns for a larger int, meaning it's actually slightly _slower_.

Comment: @abarnert Yes. It is so close that I would interpret the difference as measurement error.